# Query runs as many times as one does refresh

Tags: php

If possible i'd need help with a reload thing. I mean i have this query, which gets submitted in one page, there is this profile registration, user enters his name and surname, then he proceeds in the next page entering more specific details. if a user reloads the page i.e 4 times, that's the number of times that the user's information get inserted in the database.

is there any reload function to prevent the submission of the query?
I haven't tried anything, if you would ask me that, because i don't know how to start. the only clue i have is about using ajax, but is there any php way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow the [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://docforge.com/wiki/POST-Redirect-GET) and ALWAYS redirect after a successful POST:

Without seeing your code, you'll need a redirect like this:

```
if($inserted){
    header('Location: mypage.php?msg=reg_success');
    exit;
}
```

Then, on mypage.php, you could so something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){

    switch($_GET['msg']){

        case 'reg_success':
            echo 'Registration successful!';
        break;

    }

}
```

Or, you could create an array for success messages:

```
$success_messages = array(
    'reg_success' => 'Registration successful!',
    'logout_success' => 'Logged out!'
);
```

And then on mypage.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && array_key_exists($_GET['msg'], $success_messages)){
    $msg_index = $_GET['msg'];
    echo $success_messages[$msg_index];
}
```

Comment: This is known as the POST-redirect-GET design pattern: http://docforge.com/wiki/POST-Redirect-GET

Comment: Added that to my answer, just in case somebody else comes across the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should record all registration data in session and write them once after user click some "Finish" button.

Then redirect him and clear relavant session data.

By this way you can have any number of stage pages and nothing will be duplicated.